# Security Error when using LWJGL

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl, slick2d

I am receiving the following error after importing LWJGL as an external jar and changing the native libraries.

java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.lwjgl.opengl is sealed

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: "changing the native libraries" To what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem normaly occures when you have different versions of the JAR files. So i would start trying to check if you use compatible versions. Because sealing jars is often used to ensure version consitency. If that doesnt work, changeing the manifest files for each jar should work as well, but i acctuly dont know how to do that.